# Removing Precompiled Assets in Rails before Push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a Heroku app on Rails 4.0.8.

At some point early on, I realized that my CSS and JS changes wouldn't push to Heroku unless I ran `rake assets:precompile` and committed the new asset files before pushing (`git push heroku master`).

I've been doing those asset precompiles for about 14 months now, and I've amassed over 48mb in what appear to be old precompiled assets.  However, when I remove them from `public/assets` manually, my site loses all of its CSS and JS.

How do I remove the old precompiled assets and get Heroku to start compiling on push?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
rake assets:clean
git add .
git commit -m commit_name
git push heroku branch_name
```

This will clean your assets locally + pushing on heroku would precompile the assets.

Comment: Thanks, did that.  This is what I see when pushing to Heroku: `Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally`

Comment: Erasing the manifest file in my public assets directory appears to have done the trick!

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code.

```
rake assets:clean
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like this cleaned out the assets that weren't critical.  Now, how do I get Heroku to precompile automatically on push?

Comment: Now remove those assets from your git repo and re-push to Heroku.  Heroku will detect that you don't have precompiled assets and will compile them during the deploy process. All of this is covered in the documentation here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline